# Pandas: Repeat function for current keyword if except

Tags: python, function, selenium, pandas

I have built a web scraper. The program enters searchterm into a searchbox and grabs the results. `Pandas` goes through a spreadsheet line-by-line in a column to retrieve each searchterm.

Sometimes the page doesn't load properly, prompting a refresh.

I need a way for it to repeat the function and try the *same* searchterm if it fails. Right now, if I `return`, it would go on to the next line in the spreadsheet.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

df = pd.read_csv(searchterms.csv, delimiter=",")

def scrape(searchterm):
    #Loads url
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_name("searchbox")
    searchbox.clear()
    searchbox.send_keys(searchterm)
    print "Searching for %s ..." % searchterm

    no_result = True
    while no_result is True:
        try:
            #Find results, grab them
            no_result = False
        except:
            #Refresh page and do the above again for the current searchterm - How?
            driver.refresh()
    return pd.Series([col1, col2])

df[["Column 1", "Column 2"]] = df["searchterm"].apply(scrape)
#Executes crawl for each line in csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try` `except` construct comes with `else` clause. The `else` block is executed if everything goes OK. :

```
def scrape(searchterm):
    #Loads url

    no_result = True
    while no_result:
        #Find results, grab them
        searchbox = driver.find_element_by_name("searchbox")
        searchbox.clear()
        try: #assumes that an exception is thrown if there is no results
            searchbox.send_keys(searchterm)
            print "Searching for %s ..." % searchterm
        except:
            #Refresh page and do the above again for the current searchterm 
            driver.refresh()
        else: # executed if no exceptions were thrown
            no_results = False
            # .. some post-processing code here

    return pd.Series([col1, col2])
```

(There is also a `finally` block that is executed no matter what, which is useful for cleanup tasks that don't depend on the success or failure of the preceding code)

Also, note that empty `except` catches any exceptions and is almost never a good idea. I'm not familiar with how `selenium` handles errors, but when catching exceptions, you should specify which exception you are expecting to handle. This how, if an unexpected exception occurs, your code will abort and you'll know that something bad happened.

That is why you should also try keeping as few lines a possible within the `try` block.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So if I'm understanding this correctly, if it throws `except` it will refresh and then `try` again? And if `try` passes, it will run `else`? Or should I use `finally` for the results-processing?

Comment: Correct. Regarding the `finally` clause, see my clarification within the answer